# Excel Javascript API - Add chart with Category Axis values

Tags: javascript, excel, charts, office-js

I am adding\inserting a Line chart to Excel via the following JS call:

```
    var newSheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.add();
    newSheet.activate();

    // populate grid
    // category (axis)
    var cell = newSheet.getCell(0, 0)
    ...

    // values (axis)
    cell = newSheet.getCell(0, 1)
    ...

    var range = newSheet.getUsedRange();
    newSheet.charts.add("Line", range);
```

My "range" data looks like this:

```
2012  10
2013  20
2014  30
2015  40
2016  50
```

The issue I'm having is each column is treated as an individual series, and 2 lines are rendered in the chart. I only want one line and the Category Axis to contain the years. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Screenshot:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

Chris,

The current JavaScript API for Excel that you use to create the chart doesn't give you much control of how Excel should construct the series and axis for the chart. When using the [ChartCollection.add()](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/chartcollection.md#addtype-string-sourcedata-range-seriesby-string) method, you are depending on the "smarts" of the Excel Recommended Charts algorithm, and in this particular case the, answer it comes up with as the first answer is not what you expect.

We have an item in our API backlog to provide more fine-grained control for charts similar to what is available in other Excel APIs. At this time I can't say when this will be available in the API. I encourage you to follow our [open specification process](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/openspec) to get a heads up, and an opportunity to give feedback on our designs.

As a workaround for your particular case, I would suggest that you try using date values for the first column instead of numbers. You can format the column to show only the year part of the dates:

```
async function run() {
try {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

        let data = [
            ["Year", "Measure"],
            ["2010-12-31", 10],
            ["2011-12-31", 20], 
            ["2012-12-31", 30], 
            ["2013-12-31", 40],
            ["2014-12-31", 50],
        ];
        let format = [
            ["@"],
            ["yyyy"],
            ["yyyy"],
            ["yyyy"],
            ["yyyy"],
            ["yyyy"]
        ];

        let categories = sheet.getRange("A1:A6");
        categories.numberFormat = format;
        var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B6");
        range.values = data;

        sheet.charts.add(Excel.ChartType.line, range, Excel.ChartSeriesBy.columns);

        await context.sync();
    });
}
catch (error) {
    OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
}
```

}

This snippet is written in TypeScript using async/await, but easily be translated to JavaScript.

[image]

Jakob